# php HOW To send item on the same page as the form

Tags: php

Good day!
I am a newbie in php..
I made a form using html where I can input the grade of the student.
Then a php page to know if they pass or not.
My problem is how can i send back the reply on the html page. Example how can I send the You Failed status on my html page under the form.

My code is as follows:

```
 <HTML>
    <BODY>
    Please enter your grade (0-100 only):
    <FORM ACTION="grade2.php" METHOD="POST">
    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td>Grade</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="grade" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="grade">
    </BODY>
    </HTML>


<?php

$grade = $_POST['grade'];
IF ($grade>=0 && $grade<=50){
    print "You failed";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=60){
    print "You Passed! But Study Harder!";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=70){
    print "Nice";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=80) {
    print "Great Job";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=90){
    print "Excellent";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=100){
    print "God Like!";
} ELSE {
    print "Invalid Grade!";
}   

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one PHP page containing both the form and message. For example (assuming your file is `grade.php`)

```
<form action="grade.php" method="post">
    <!-- form elements, etc -->
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {
    $grade = (double) $_POST['grade'];
    // if statements, print message, etc
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see that may prevent it from showing up now is that the print statements are outside the `<body>` tags.

Move

```
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

to the very end of the file

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways that you can use.

You can echo the script filename:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

Or just leave the action field blank. The page will then re-load on itself.

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

At the top of your script, test for the presence of POST variables on the reload:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

And that's it.

Comment: **Never** blindly use `PHP_SELF` in a form action without sanitising it first using `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`. Google [PHP_SELF XSS](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP_SELF+XSS)

Comment: Can someone get in using the second option? The one without PHP?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean send as in email, use the mail() function.

If you mean just print the result to the screen, use echo.

```
<?php

$grade = $_POST['grade'];
IF ($grade>=0 && $grade<=50){
    echo "You failed";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=60){
    echo "You Passed! But Study Harder!";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=70){
    echo "Nice";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=80) {
    echo "Great Job";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=90){
    echo "Excellent";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=100){
    echo "God Like!";
} ELSE {
    echo "Invalid Grade!";
}   

?>
```

Also, i'm not sure if this is a standard or not (I usually don't see it that way), but having all caps in your IF / ELSE statements really annoys me for some reason.

Comment: `print` and `echo` perform the same basic function